# How to update a database on server using a DACPAC in Azure Pipeline without dropping and recreating the database

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) database project, and when I deploy it, it drops and recreates the database/tables/stored procedures etc.

My scenario is that I want it not to drop the database and only update the stored procedures or tables where changes have been made. I'd like to keep the existing tables and other objects on the server intact.

For example, if I make a change in just one table, the DACPAC should only update that specific table on the server, regardless of any other differences, even if they don't match the source

We are using a DACPAC file through an Azure pipeline for deployment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show sqlproj contents (configuration options, not your sql files) and the command used for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got the [CreateNewDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.createnewdatabase?view=sql-dacfx-162) property set to `True`

it could be command line publish parameter:

`/p CreateNewDatabase=True`

Or it could be set in the publish xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ... other properties ...
    <CreateNewDatabase>True</CreateNewDatabase>
```

Or in the publish UI (which sets the above mentioned XML property):

[image]

Comment: after adding parameter you suggested my DB got deleted from server and results the following error:   
Analyzing deployment plan (Complete) 
Updating database (Start) 
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. 
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%. 
Creating SSDT-Demo... 
An error occurred while the batch was being executed. 
Updating database (Failed)

Comment: Was the `CreateNewDatabase` property already set to True and then you changed it to `False`?